# How to arrange UICollectionVewCell from top to bottom then left to right

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

**Question** : How can I align `UICollectionViewCell` from top to bottom then left to right?

**Current Situation** : I have left to right and top to bottom which is normal behavior of it.

**Check image** :

[image]

**MyCell.swift :**

```
import UIKit
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblCell: UILabel!
}
```

**myCollectionVC.swift :**

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class myCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var simpleCell: UICollectionViewCell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //Test behavior with static number
        return 100
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: MyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("My_Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell;
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
        cell.lblCell.text = String(indexPath.row + 1);
        return cell
    }

}
```

How can I cells from top to bottom then left to right?

```
[1][5][9][13]
[2][6][10][14]
[3][7][11][15]
[4][8][12][16]
...
...
```

In worst case I will try static method alignment of cells.
In my example is just a sample. Actually it must be a dynamic variable.

Comment: what should be the scroll direction ? should it be left to right .

Comment: @V-Xtreme. No need to do scroll direction. I plan to use UIPageView for next numbers. My attachment is misleading I am fixing it.

Comment: I'm assuming you initialize your view controller with a flow layout ? If yes, check the `scrollDirection` property of the flow layout.

Comment: @deadbeef. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change scroll direction to Horizontal from Attribute Inspector as shown into below image:

[image]

And your result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I've never though it will be so easy like this.

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)